# Implementation of cross-classified multilevel mediation in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, mediation

I want to model the effect of the experimental factor *x* on the response variable *y*. However, we also want to test whether the effect of *x* on *y* is mediated by the mediator *m*. We aim to model this using a multilevel setup, in which the stimuli *stimulus* are nested within individuals *id*. Regarding the random effects, we assume random intercepts for both levels and propose a random slope for *x* within *id*.

However, the experimental data structure is not perfectly hierarchical, as within each experiment we presented the same 30 stimuli to the participants, except for the manipulation of the experimental factor *x*. Thus, we obtain a cross-classified data structure with a counterbalanced design, which we intend to model with cross-classified multilevel modeling (Hox, 2002).

Is the implementation of cross-classified data structures supported in the R package “mediation”? Is the relationship between the variables adequately modeled using the following code?

```
library(lme4)
library(mediation)
model1 <- lmer(m ~ x + (x|id) + (1|stimulus), data=df, method = "ML")
model2 <- lmer(y ~ m + x + (x|id) + (1|stimulus), data=df, method = "ML")
mediation <- mediate(model1, model2, treat = "x", mediator = "m", sims = 100)
```